# how do i loop over values within a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
    1   1   2   2
    2   2   1   1
```

I have written a function which:

- takes the df in a for loop,
- adds row(s) with a default value
- replaces the values with another value in randomly selected cols
- writes to csv

**This is my code:**

```
def add_x(df, max):
    gt_w_x = df.copy()
    counter = 0


    for i in range(1, max):
        if len(gt_w_x) != max:
            counter+=1
            # add new row with default value
            gt_w_x.loc[-1,:] = 1
        
            # reset index
            gt_w_x = gt_w_x.reset_index(drop=True)
        
            # how to loop over these values for x ??
            x = 1
            #x = 2
        
            # assign value 'X' to x randomly selected cols on last row 
            gt_w_x.iloc[-1:, random.sample(list(range(gt_w_x.shape[1])), x)] = 'X'
        
            x = str(x)
            n = str(counter)
        
            # write to file
            df_path = 'test/' + x + '_' + n + '.csv'
            gt_w_x.to_csv(df_path) 

max = 4
add_x(df, max)
```

**The output on my system is**

```
test/1_1.csv  
test/1_2.csv  


cat test/1_1.csv    
0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0  
1,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0  
2,1.0,X,1.0,1.0  


cat test/1_2.csv  
0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0  
1,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0  
2,1.0,X,1.0,1.0  
3,1.0,X,1.0,1.0
```

How do I loop over values for x?
The desired output for `x = 1` and `x = 2` is

```
test/1_1.csv  
test/1_2.csv  
test/2_1.csv    
test/2_2.csv
```

Currently, I run the function by commenting out different values for x which is suboptimal.

Comment: Use another `for` loop for the different `x` values.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a question here.  "How do I loop over values for x?" Well, do you see how the code already loops over values for i? Did you try doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested for loop. It works just like the one you have at the beginning of the function:

```python
def add_x(df, max):
    for x in range(1,3):
        gt_w_x = df.copy()
        counter = 0

        for i in range(1, max):
            if len(gt_w_x) != max:
                counter+=1
                # add new row with default value
                gt_w_x.loc[-1,:] = 1

                # reset index
                gt_w_x = gt_w_x.reset_index(drop=True)

                # assign value 'X' to x randomly selected cols on last row
                gt_w_x.iloc[-1:, random.sample(list(range(gt_w_x.shape[1])), x)] = 'X'

                n = str(counter)

                # write to file
                df_path = 'test/' + str(x) + '_' + n + '.csv'
                gt_w_x.to_csv(df_path)

max = 4
add_x(df, max)
```

Comment: This does not appear to give the right output. In the file test/1_2.csv there are two rows containing X, which is correct. However, the first of these X-containing rows has X in three columns and the second X-containing row has X in one column. Maybe I'm missing something. Would you be willing to check?

Comment: Hi @peter_parker, I updated the looping order for x and inlined the relevant str(x) function so it won't change x mid-loop.